# How can i use bool to create a file

Tags: c++

Hi can someone help me with this function:

```
bool createfile (string path);
```

It is supposed to create a file but my problem is:
What exactly the `true` or `false` have to do with creating a file?! How can I use it?

Comment: Here the `bool` is the return value from the function. I expect your teacher wants that you return true if the file was successfully created and false if something went wrong. Feels it is a good time to read your first C++ beginner book!

Comment: `bool` is the **return type** of the function.  I see far too many people get confused and say "a bool" or "a void" when they mean a function.  For pure functions, the return value is arguable the most important thing, but there are a lot of functions which are not "pure" and the important thing is the side effect.  That includes yours.  The effect on the file system is the important part of the function, and the return value probably tells you something such as whether it failed to create, or whether the file already existed.

Comment: The exact side effects and the exact meaning of each return value would be found in *documentation*.  Get used to writing good documentation for your code, and insist on documentation for code that people (such as your professor) give to you.

Answer (score 0):

The `bool` is the return type of the function `createfile()`. Without the definition it is impossible to tell for sure what exactly this value is supposed to be, but often it is used to return if the function was successful in doing what it is supposed to do, in this case, create a file.

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly the true or false have to do with creating a file?!

You might want to return `true` if the file was successfully created or `false` otherwise.

> How can I use it?

This depends on the body of the function and the purpose that you want to use the function for.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick answer

To directly answer the *"How can I use it"* part of your question:
You call it this way:

```cpp
string path = "/path/to/my/file.txt";
bool returnedValue = createfile(path);
```

As for *"What exactly the true or false have to do with creating a file?!"*, like mentionned in the other answers, it might indicate the success or failure of the operation, but you might want to double-check that, because the actual value will depend on the implementation of `bool createfile(string path)`...

### Comprehensive answer

It seems you need some help interpreting the syntax of `bool createfile(string path);`

What we need to clarify here is that in `c++` (and many other languages), the first word used in the function declaration is the *return type*.
You could compare this to some arbitrary mathematical function of the following form:  here

```
x = a + b
```

In this case, `x` is the result of the addition function.
Assuming all the elements above are numbers, we could translate this in `c++`, like so:

```cpp
int a = 0;
int b = 5;
int x = a + b;
```

We could extract the example above in a function (to reuse the addition), like so:

```cpp
int add(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

and use it in the following way (with a `main` to put some execution context around it):

```cpp
int main()
{
  int x = add(0,5);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Here are some other examples of functions:

```cpp
// simple non-member function returning int
int f1()
{
    return 42;
}
 
// function that returns a boolean
bool f2(std::string str)
{ 
    return std::stoi(str) > 0;
}
```

You'll find more details [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function). It might seem like a lot to take in (the page is dense with information), but it is a true reference.